# Lazy Loading TreeViewItem with custom loading method depending on their nested type

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, lazy-loading

Let's say I have a collection of employees. The employees can be a senior supervisor, junior supervisor or a trainee.
These 3 types of employees are classes derived from employee. Each Senior supervisor guids a group of junior supervisors. Each junior supervisor guids a group of trainees.

[image: UML]

`LoadChilds` fill the `Childs` Collection.

Now i want to show their hierarchy from senior to trainee in a **treeview** by using **lazy initialization**. I would like call the method `LoadChilds`on `TreeViewItem.Exapand` event. ( I am open for other ideas.)

Currently i am presenting the different datatypes by a HierarchicalDataTemplate.

```
<TreeView x:Name="Tree">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Supervisor}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Employee}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**Question:** How can I call a method, edit the data und refresh the UI on Expanding a TreeViewItem?

Comment: My question simply set as "put on hold" does not help me. Just say what is unclear. Especially others understand the question and the solution has already been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is definitely a "prettier" way - without writing business logic in event handler in code-behind.

introduce boolean `IsExpanded` in a view model classes, bind `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` to that property and trigger `LoadChilds` method in setter:

```
<TreeView x:Name="Tree">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:A}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:B}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        // null is a placeholder. 
        // without any items TreeViewItem will not even show expander
        // (Expand event won't work either)
        Childs = new ObservableCollection<B>() { null };
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _isExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            // when node is expanded, RELOAD!
            if (_isExpanded)
                LoadChilds();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<B> Childs { get; set; }

    public void LoadChilds()
    {
        Childs.Clear();
        Childs.Add(new B() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
    }
}
```

`B` is almost identical in this test example, but I suppose LoadChilds logic will be different in a real app

```
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        Childs = new ObservableCollection<B>() { null };
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _isExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            if (_isExpanded)
                LoadChilds();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<B> Childs { get; set; }

    public void LoadChilds()
    {
        Childs.Clear();
        Childs.Add(new B() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface that both `A` and `B` implements and cast the `DataContext` of the expanded `TreeViewItem` to this type:

```
public interface ICommon
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void LoadChilds(DBConnection connection);
}

public class A : ICommon
{
    public class A()
    {
        Childs = new ObservableCollection<B>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<B> Childs { get; set; }
    public void LoadChilds(DBConnection connection) //Type is unimportant
    {
        // adding childs
    }
}

public class B : ICommon
{
    public class B()
    {
        Childs = new ObservableCollection<B>(); //Yes, rekursiv
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<B> Childs { get; set; }
    public void LoadChilds(DBConnection connection)
    {
        // adding childs
    } 
}
```

---

```
private void TreeView_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    ICommon obj = tvi.DataContext as ICommon;
    if (obj != null)
        obj.LoadChilds(...);

}
```

Comment: Currently i do something like that. Is there a "prettier" way? I want to avoid as many dependencies as possible. An interface is a dependency.

Comment: "An interface is a dependency" should rather be an interface is an abstraction. No, there is no "prettier" way. If you don't implement an interface you will have to try to cast the DataContext to an A *and* a *B* and a C and any other concrete type that may be involved.